# Firestore does not store the timestamp accurately

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

When I am writing a document with a date inside to Firestore and do an instant request on this Document, I get a slightly different response.

```
let testDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.23894623798574298572)
print("BEFORE:")
print(Timestamp(date: testDate))
    
ffs.collection("cities").document("LA").setData([
    "date": Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.23894623798574298572)
]) { err in
    self.ffs.collection("cities").document("LA").getDocument(){ (document,err) in
        if let document = document {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"     
            print("AFTER:")
            print(dataDescription)
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist in cache")
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
BEFORE:
<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1626522770 nanoseconds=767140150>
AFTER:
["date": <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1626522770 nanoseconds=770540000>]
```

Why are the nanoseconds different? I would have expected them to be equal or at least rounded somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Firestore stores date and time as Firestore-native `Timestamp` objects, not Swift-native `Date` objects. And the `Timestamp` object, as we interface with it on the client, is a token. This means that when we create a `Timestamp` object, we cannot give it a concrete value (a specific date and time), we merely create a token that represents now. When the server eventually executes the write, it will then redeem that token (by giving it a value) and store that value in the database. This explains the discrepancy between now on the client and now in the server.